# Enable and disable onclick funtion

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically creating a table where i am adding onclick function to each column.

```js
for (var x = 0; x < r.length; x++) {
    //Setting the columns
    if (i === 1) {
        var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
        headerCell.innerHTML = r[x];
        headerCell.id = x;
        headerCell.onclick = function () {
            sortTable(this.id, name);
        }
        row.appendChild(headerCell);

    }
}
```

In a specific situation I want to disable the onclick function. Here is the code and it works.

```
 $('#errorTable TH').prop("onclick", null).off("click");
```

and in another situation i want to reattach the onclick function. And that doesn't work. I want to enable the original function....

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you try to reattach the `onclick` function?

Comment: have you tried addEventListener  to reattach click event?

Comment: I prefer adding one event handler to the table itself instead of having to mess with when to attach/detach an event from a specific cell.

Answer (score 0):

The way you created your table and adding/removing events are not easily maintainable. I also have some suggestions:

- Review your code and define code click handler separately.
- If you use jQuery in your project use it every where, if not, do not use it anywhere.
- In your code `i` is undefined.

**Add Remove Event Listener with jQuery**

First define your handler function:

```
var myClickHandler = function(){
// this is your click handler
    alert('Yes!!!');
}
```

Select your element and assign to a variable. `<div id="clickable">Click Me!</div>` must be in the DOM at the time of below script executed.

```
var element = $('#clickable');
// assign event listener

element.on('click',myClickHandler);

// remove event listener:

element.off('click',myClickHandler);
```

**note that you must have to inform jQuery which handler should be removed.**

See a sample https://codepen.io/softberry/pen/BEpove

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to build a click handler that checks a "kill switch".

```
var tableClickable = true;

headerCell.onclick = function () {
  if (tableClickable) {
    sortTable(this.id, name);
  }
}

//In a specific situation I want to disable the onclick function.
something.addEventListener('someEvent', function () {
  tableClickable = false;
});

//and in another situation i want to reattach the onclick function.
something.addEventListener('someOtherEvent', function () {
  tableClickable = true;
});
```